# IPTABLES How to block 8.8.8.8

Tags: dns, ip, block, iptables

I am creating a script that allows you to block, IP, port, certain IP's and ports, and DNS servers. It basically gets a name and blocks certain addresses for that person.
Problem is, I am stuck at blocking 8.8.8.8 . No matter what I have tried, I cannot seem to block it!

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 8.8.8.8 --destination-port 53 -j DROP
 iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 8.8.8.8 --destination-port 53 -j DROP
 iptables -A OUTPUT -p -s 8.8.8.8 -j DROP
```

And even

```
 iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j DROP
```

Pinging any other site doesn't work, while pinging 8.8.8.8 still works...

My Policies are all set to ALLOW. Should I change them?

I am kinda new to this, apologies if this all seems queer . Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to block a SOURCE address in the OUTPUT chain. 8.8.8.8 would be a DESTINATION in the output chain. The SOURCE of a packet in the output chain is generally the machine you're running these rules on... Try these:

```
-A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8 -j DROP
```

rule #1 will drop any packets coming **IN** to your system which originated on google's public DNS. rule #2 will drop any packets LEAVING your system destined for the same.

As for ping, remember that ping uses the ICMP protocol. You're trying to block UDP only. Also remember that DNS requests **CAN** use TCP if the request or response would need more than 1 udp packet.